# vb.net press/release keys

Tags: vb.net, keyboard

How can you simulate keypresses and releases? I know you can essentially hit a key with `Sendkeys.SendWait`, but how can your code press and hold <kbd>Q</kbd>, for example?

Any help is much appreciated! Everything I find keeps pointing me at sendkeys, which is not correct.

I essentially wish to be able to call something like `press("q")` and `release("q")`. The effect would be the same as physically holding them down.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions.

Comment: Not SendMessage.  Google "vb.net declare sendinput" to find samples.